# PHP date one day off when loaded in page - Possibly WordPress issue?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time

My code is displaying the date one day off when loaded in my page, but displays normal when called by itself.

Here is the code:

```
<?

if(!$_GET[date])
    {
    $theDate = date(m).date(d).date(y);
    }
else
    {
    $theDate = $_GET[date]; 
    }
    echo $theDate;
/// more code but not necessary to show
?>
```

When I load in with an include in my home page you see the date is one day a head.
See it here: http://edvizenor.com/?p=Catholic-Daily-Mass-Readings

However, when I load the exact same code but the page by itself the date is right.
See it here: http://edvizenor.com/Catholic-Daily-Mass-Readings.php

My only thought is "maybe" it is a word press issue because my code does call Word Press and perhaps that is changing the server date? Nevertheless how do I fix this?

I don't think it would be right to subtract 1, since this might mess it up at some point.

UPDATE:  I narrowed it down to Word Press for sure.
Its coming from this line because when I hide it then it works.

```
include('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

But I don't know what to change in the word press. Could the MySQl Database time be off?

Comment: Use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the correct timezone for your application.

Comment: @PeterMichael yep that did it! Thanks my friend. Feel free to add that as an answer and I will mark it right. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the correct timezone for your application. –  Peter Michael Oct 21 at 6:09

Answer (score 0):

check timezone setting in wordpress . You are displaying time directly while wordpress will be converting it to timezone you selected in settings.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/general-settings/#timezone

Also this might help

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: I set it to Los Angeles as I am in Sacramento CA. But it still seems to be having the same issue. Here is a screen shot link: http://oi42.tinypic.com/29eisqt.jpg

Comment: blue date "OCTOBER 21, 2013" is that wordpress or theme code ? If yes something is up there with theme you are using . If that date is not part of wordpress/theme code you need to change the code in the place to use proper timezone.

Comment: No the blue date comes from this code: <? echo date(F) . " " . date(j) . ", " . date(Y); ?> Its just php with css

Comment: Its coming from this line because when I hide it then it works. include('blog/wp-blog-header.php'); But I don't know what to change in the word press. Could the MySQl Database time be off?